# How to store large JSON documents(>20MB) in MongoDB without using GridFS

Tags: json, mongodb, architecture

I want to store a large document in MongoDB, however, these are the two ways I will interact with the document:

1. I do frequent reads of that data and need to get a part of that data using aggregations
2. When I need to write to the document, I will be building it from scratch again, i.e remove the document that exists and insert a new one.

Here is how a sample document looks like:

```json
{
    "objects_1": [
        {
        
        }
    ],
    "objects_2": [
        {
        
        }
    ],
    "objects_3": [
        {
        
        }
    ],
    "policy_1": [
        {
        
        }
    ],
    "policy_2": [
        {
        
        }
    ],
    "policy_3": [
        {
        
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is how I want to access that data:

```json
{
"objects_1": [
        {

        }
}
```

If I was storing it in a conventional way, I would write a query like this:

```
db.getCollection('configuration').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: "FAAAAAAAAAAAA" } },
    { $project: {
        "_id": 0,
        "a_objects": {
            $filter: {
                input: "$settings.a_objects",
                as: "arrayItem",
                cond: { $eq: [ "$$arrayItem.name", "objectName" ] }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

However, since the size of the document is >16 MB, we cant save it directly to MongoDB. The size can be a max of 50MB.

Solutions I thought of:

1. I thought of storing the json data in gridfs format and reading it as per the docs here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/ . However, then I would need to read the entire file every time I want to look up only one object inside the large json blob, and I need to do such reads frequently, on multiple large documents which would lead to high memory usage
2. I thought of splitting the json into parts and storing each object in it's own separate collection, and when I need to fetch the entire document, I can reassemble the json

How should I approach this problem? Is there something obvious that I am missing here?

Comment: `I would need to read the entire file every time` - that's true no matter how the document is stored in MongoDB.  It never reads only part of a document from disk, always the entire thing.

Comment: @Joe what I mean to say is that I think it is much more efficient if mongo does the reading vs me reading the large file into memory and extracting some part of it

Comment: Split your data into multiple documents, use aggregation pipeline to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're not using the right tools for the job, or not using the tools you have in the way they were meant to be used.

If you want to persist large objects as JSON then I'd argue that a database isn't a natural choice for that - especially if the objects are large.  I'd be looking at storage systems designed to do that well (say if your solution is on Azure/AWS/GCP see what specialist service they offer) or even just the file system if you run on a local server.

There's no reason why you can't have the JSON in a file and related data in a database - yes there are issues with that but the limitations of MongoDB won't be one of them.

> I do frequent reads of that data and need to get a part of that data using aggregations

If you are doing frequent reads, and only for part of the data, then forcing your system to always read the whole record means you are just penalizing yourself.  One option is to store the bits that are highly read in a way that doesn't incur the performance penalty of the full read.

Storing objects as JSON means you can change your program and data without having to worry about what the database looks like, its convenient.  But it also has it's limitations.  If you think you have hit those limitations then now might be the time to consider a re-architecture.

> I thought of splitting the JSON into parts and storing each object in it's own separate collection, and when I need to fetch the entire document, I can reassemble the JSON

That's definably worth looking into.  You just need to make sure that the different parts are not stored in the same table / rows, otherwise there'll be no improvement.  Think carefully about how you spilt the objects up - think about the key scenarios the objects deal with - e.g. you mention reads.  Designing the sub-objects to align with key scenarios is the way to go.

For example, if you commonly show an object's summary in a list of object summaries (e.g. search results), then the summary text, object name, id are candidates for object data that you would split out.

Comment: thanks for the insight, unfortunately, using json is a requirement, hence I cant change that.